# What does it mean for the git commit history to have a different colour in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm trying to understand how Android Studio/IntelliJ tries to show the git history visually.

Sometimes, I have different coloured commits like this:

[image]

What does it mean for the latest commit to be in purple and the rest in brown? This is on the main branch btw.

Does it have something to do with branches diverging?

Comment: I haven't used the tool so this is a guess: maybe the purple commit hasn't been pushed yet, but the others have? If you type `git status` and this is the case, you'll see you're one commit ahead.

Comment: I'm not a commit ahead of remote. The latest commit has been merged into main through a PR and pulled locally.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an Android Studio bug?

Because my graph now looks to be all in the same colour for the main branch.